# SQL Server - optimize execution of UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the following query on a table of 12 columns and approximately 5 million records:

```
UPDATE dbo.Capture
SET STATUS = 501,
BATCH = NULL
WHERE STATUS = 1
```

The count of records where `STATUS = 1` is approximately 4 million records.  The query ran for an hour before I finally canceled it because:

1. An hour had passed, and this is very abnormal length of time for our SQL databases to run an UPDATE query.
2. We have a Service Fabric Application which interacts with this database, and after about 10 minutes of this query running, we started getting health errors thrown from the Service Fabric Cluster, on what seemed to be on account of this query locking up the database.

My question is whether there is a more efficient way to go about updating these 4 million records.  Should I try and batch the updates, and if so, how is this accomplished in a query?

I have an auto-index-degfragmenter which runs every 24 hours so fragmentation of indexes should not be causing any issue.

Comment: "auto-index-degfragmenter which runs every 24 hours so fragmentation of indexes should not be causing any issue." You still have to specify which column you want to index. Look my solution and let me know if it works please.

Comment: Updating 4 million records in a single transaction is proably blowing out your transaction log. Consider breaking the update into several smaller batches

Comment: Update by batches or set table-level lock to avoid concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're updating approximately 80% of your rows, breaking it up may be the simplest way to do it.  Here's one method (assuming that Capture has primary key column named ID):

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Capture WHERE Status=1) BEGIN

UPDATE c1 
SET STATUS = 501, 
BATCH = NULL 
FROM Capture c1 
JOIN (SELECT TOP 10000 ID FROM Capture WHERE STATUS = 1) c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID

END
```

Comment: Stuart, this looks like it may be exactly what I need.  I will test this today and mark as answer if it works as I expect it will.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You still have to index your column `STATUS` of your table `dbo.Capture`. It will run your query hundreds time faster!

Here is how to:

```
CREATE INDEX index_status ON dbo.Capture (STATUS);
```

Comment: Jonathan, fantastic! I will do this.  Once the index is created, any idea how long it will take for the index to build after the completion of its creation, before the query runs more quickly?  I am asking because I don't want to kick off the UPDATE query again until I know the column is fully indexed. Or, is it fully-indexed once I get the Command Completed Successfully message?

Comment: It will be instant. The time to build the index will slow down, however, once created you will see the difference. ;)